# WSO2 response binary?

Tags: binary, response, wso2

I have a http service exposed in WSO2. The service address is `"http://172.30.60.73:8888/XMPPService/recieveMsg?param=yes"`, and the response is `"notifyresult=000000"`.But

in WSO2, The log output is : `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><axis2ns7:binary xmlns:axis2ns7="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">bm90aWZ5cmVzdWx0PTAwMDAwMDENCg==</axis2ns7:binary></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>`

I use script mediator:

```
 var symbol=mc.getPayloadXML().toString();
 var response=symbol.substring(13,symbol.length)
 mc.setPayloadXML(<p:createGroupResponse xmlns:p="http://iag.sdp.coship.com/xmpp/"><notifyresult>{ response }</notifyresult></p:createGroupResponse>);
```

And the client side is:

```
  <p:createGroupResponse xmlns:p="http://iag.sdp.coship.com/xmpp/">
     <notifyresult>Wx0PTAwMDAwMDENCg==</notifyresult>
  </p:createGroupResponse>
```

Seems the response is binary. How to convert this response to `"notifyresult=000000"`. Anyone can help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you getting this binary response at client side? or is this a log mediator output? decode the message body using base64..and check

Answer (score 0):

By default ESB uses the passthrough transport in version 4.6.0.In passthrough we dont build the message..Can you switch to NIO transport and check? Edit the axis2.xml , transport listener, sender fro NIO transport